# How to compare a character with a hex value in php?

Tags: php, comparison, hex

I have the following problem in PHP. I want to compare a character (string) with a hex value, see the following example code:

```
// some key defined in some other application. I only can use KEY1
define("KEY1", 0x31);

// the test value
$sValue = '1';

// the comparison which I would like not to modify
print ($sValue == KEY1) ? "true" : "false";
```

As `0x31` represents 49 decimal which is the character '`1`', I expect to see a `true`. Instead I see a `false`. How to get it right **without** using anything different than `KEY1`? Maybe the type of `sValue` is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for

```
print ($sValue == chr(KEY1)) ? "true" : "false";
```

or, alternatively,

```
print (ord($sValue) == KEY1) ? "true" : "false";
```